# English grammar parsing in PHP (Link Grammar)

Tags: c#, php, parsing, nlp

Is there any way to use the Link Grammar or AbiSource grammar checker in PHP (or C# but I'd prefer php)? I need to have a tree structure for English sentences. Any ideas? The only things I found were in C and I can't use them on a shared host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [SharpNLP](http://sharpnlp.codeplex.com/), which does phrase-structure parsing.

Link Grammar doesn't have PHP bindings (or C# bindings). You'd have to write your own bindings. And Link Grammar is written in C, so if you can't put your own C code on a shared host, then you can't use Link Grammar.